# How should I handle 'this' in javascript objects that contain other javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I'm using John Resig's excellent javascript class for [simple javascript inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) and I'm having a spot of bother getting my head around some variable scope problems in relation to the 'this' keyword.

My extended class looks a little like this

```
var EUNode = Class.extend({

    // Methods
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    init : function(){

        this.div = this.createDiv();
        this.canDoStuff = true;
        this.div.addEventListener(touchstart, this.touchStartHandler, false);

    },



    // Create Div
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    createDiv : function(){

        // code to create a DIV element, add some classes and do some 
        // other useful stuff

    },

    touchStartHandler : function(event){

        // In here, 'this' refers to the div element, so the 
        // following condition doesn't work
        if(this.canDoStuff){

            // do some stuff

        }

    }

});
```

I need to be able to reference the EUNode instance from inside the `touchStartEventHandler`, so I tried the following

```
var EUNode = Class.extend({

    // Methods
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    init : function(){

            this._super();
            // Store a reference to 'this' globally
        self = this; 
        self.div = this.createDiv();
        self.canDoStuff = true;
        self.div.addEventListener(touchstart, self.touchStartHandler, false);

    },

    touchStartHandler : function(event){

        if(self.canDoStuff){

            // Now I can do stuff, but 'self' is now a global variable
                    // which isn't what I want. If there's more than one instance
                    // of EUNode, 'self' references the newest instance.

        }

    }

});
```

So I'm stuck in a loop. It seems that in order to limit the scope of "self" globally, I need to use the "this" keyword, but "this" means something else inside event handlers. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, global variables are bad (in general). As you noticed yourself, you already get in trouble if you have two EUNode instances because the last one would override the global `self`.

You are also making `touchStartHandler` dependent on some global variable, and the whole working of this function might not be so clear anymore.

Just call `touchStartHandler` in the right context:

```
init : function(){
    var self = this;  // <- local `self`

    this.div = this.createDiv();
    this.canDoStuff = true;

    // pass a closure, making `self` available inside the function
    this.div.addEventListener(touchstart, function(event) {
        self.touchStartHandler(event);
    }, false);
},
```

In browsers supporting ECMAScript 5 you can also use [**`.bind()`** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (see link for an implementation for other browsers) to bind the element `this` should refer to:

```
this.div.addEventListener(touchstart, this.touchStartHandler.bind(this), false);
```

Comment: +1 I'd like to put emphasis on the fact that it is always wrong to omit the `var` keyword. This makes all the difference in regard to the OPs scope issue.

Comment: simple simple simple. I much prefer the 'bind()' function since it keeps the code neater. Sadly, this is specifically for a cocoa WebView implementation.

Comment: @gargantaun: Mmh. Maybe you can still extend `Function.prototype`. Have a look at the link. But the other way is not bad either and is common practice to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you establish the event handler, just wrap the call to "touchStartHandler()" in an anonymous function, such that you call it through the appropriate instance of your class.

In other words:

```
var boundHandler = function(event) { yourInstance.touchStartHandler(event); };
```

Then the function "boundHandler" can be used to handle the events, and the real code will always be set up with `this` referencing the right object.

There's also a function in newer browsers called ".bind()" that lets you do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
self.div.addEventListener(touchstart, self.touchStartHandler, false);
```

Try

```
self.div.addEventListener(touchstart, function(event) { self.touchStartHandler(event) }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.touchStartHandler.bind(self)`